# Node.js/Typescript - getting current filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Using Node.js with standard JavaScript, it's possible to use the path module to get the current filename, something like this:

```
// my-script.js
var path = require('path');
var scriptName = path.basename(__filename);
```

However, when using TypeScript, the above (in a file called my-script.ts) will output something like `index`, regardless of what the TypeScript file is called. I'm guessing this is because at runtime, the TypeScript file has been compiled into JavaScript, and the `my-script.ts` file no longer exists.

With this in mind, how can I get the name of the file using TypeScript?

Comment: Does [this](https://ts-morph.com/navigation/getting-source-files) help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know your typescript file, you will need to play with source maps.
And from throwing and catching that you can get the place where is originated.